# Android activity with TimePicker object in Japanese Locale crashing when device is rotated

Tags: android, timepicker

I am experiencing an issue in my app where when user rotate the device when an actvity  with time picker object in the layout, it crashes.  We could only replicate in Japanese and other Asian locale only and app works fine in other languages. To rule out any issue on our side, I created a simple test activity that loads this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
 <TimePicker
            android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />
```

If I rotate the device, it works fine in English locale (or if android:visibility is not gone) but if device is in Japanese locale, app crashes with following exception:

```
 07-23 21:46:02.939: E/AndroidRuntime(22524): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-23 21:46:02.939: E/AndroidRuntime(22524): Process: com.example.datepickertest, PID: 22524
07-23 21:46:02.939: E/AndroidRuntime(22524): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (2 ... 2) ends beyond length 0
07-23 21:46:02.939: E/AndroidRuntime(22524):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1016)
07-23 21:46:02.939: E/AndroidRuntime(22524):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:592)
07-23 21:46:02.939: E/AndroidRuntime(22524):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:588)
07-23 21:46:02.939: E/AndroidRuntime(22524):    at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:76)
07-23 21:46:02.939: E/AndroidRuntime(22524):    at android.widget.EditText.setSelection(EditText.java:87)
07-23 21:46:02.939: E/AndroidRuntime(22524):    at android.widget.NumberPicker$SetSelectionCommand.run(NumberPicker.java:2123)
07-23 21:46:02.939: E/AndroidRuntime(22524):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-23 21:46:02.939: E/AndroidRuntime(22524):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-23 21:46:02.939: E/AndroidRuntime(22524):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-23 21:46:02.939: E/AndroidRuntime(22524):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
07-23 21:46:02.939: E/AndroidRuntime(22524):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-23 21:46:02.939: E/AndroidRuntime(22524):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-23 21:46:02.939: E/AndroidRuntime(22524):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
07-23 21:46:02.939: E/AndroidRuntime(22524):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
07-23 21:46:02.939: E/AndroidRuntime(22524):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Anyone else ever experienced this issue? Any input will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: Found a temporary fix based on comment #5 here:https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22754

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities which solved the problem in my case (for TimePicker or NumberPicker):

i.) call these methods in your onCreate after calling findViewbyID:

TimePicker.setSaveFromParentEnabled(false);
TimePicker.setSaveEnabled(false);

(found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31702937/4240534)

ii.) set your TimePicker to INVISIBLE instead of GONE (if this is possible concerning your layout design)

```
<TimePicker code here
android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:visibility="invisible" />
```