# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (5 ... 5) ends beyond length 0 on Device Back button press

Tags: java, android

On Back press I am getting an error "`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (5 ... 5) ends beyond length 0`" I am not understanding where I am getting this error. This error is happening when I pass Device Back button and came to fragment page (FragmentPageA). If I came to the same page(FragmentPageA) by tapping on Menu I am not getting the same error.

```
    08-19 17:00:42.119 1252-1252/com.shidhin.ts E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (5 ... 5) ends beyond length 0
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1265)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:684)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:677)
        at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:76)
        at android.widget.TextView.semSetSelection(TextView.java:11549)
        at android.widget.EditText.setSelection(EditText.java:118)
        at android.widget.NumberPicker$SetSelectionCommand.run(NumberPicker.java:2246)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
08-19 17:00:42.388 1252-1252/com.shidhin.ts E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.shidhin.ts, PID: 1252
        java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (5 ... 5) ends beyond length 0
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1265)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:684)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:677)
        at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:76)
        at android.widget.TextView.semSetSelection(TextView.java:11549)
        at android.widget.EditText.setSelection(EditText.java:118)
        at android.widget.NumberPicker$SetSelectionCommand.run(NumberPicker.java:2246)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

Here is my Back press Code on the Activity Page,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(menuLayout))
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(menuLayout);
    else {
        if (getFragmentManager() != null && getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else
            showExitConfirmationDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code as well.

Comment: @SurenSaluka I am not understand where I am getting this issue. I want to know what will be the reasons for this issue.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the onCreate() method of FragmentPageA and simulate the scenario. Without having the code of onCreate() method in FragmentPageA it's hard to guess what went wrong.

Comment: Share some code

Comment: @MarcoPierucci It's happening when I tap on Device Back button, When I tap on back button it loads the previous fragment and after few seconds I am getting this Issue. When I select the same page from Menu there is no issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like someone else had the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31030704/android-numberpicker-index-outofbounds-rotation)

```
NumberPicker.setSaveFromParentEnabled(false);       
NumberPicker.setSaveEnabled(false);
```

Comment: :) Thanks, This Solved my problem